# Gathering variable numbers of rows into fixed-width time intervals

Tags: r

I'm relatively new to R, so I may have overlooked function that is already in R. I have already created a solution using loops, but am wondering if there is a R way to do this (up until now, all of my R scripts have been loop-less, as they should be!)

The data consists of one CSV record for an event. The event has an ISO-8601 timestamp, a response time, and a response code (indicating success or the particular failure). I can convert this CSV into a data frame, and create an R date and time field from the timestamp string. No problem so far.

I then determine the size of a fixed-length time interval for analysis and plotting purposes. For example, let's assume 5 minutes. For the first 5-minute interval there may be 151 events (rows in the data frame). For the next 5-minute interval, there may be only 130 events. And so on. In other words, the client whose logs are being analyzed has an uneven request load with a varying request rate. What I need to do is take each 5-minute time interval, and then for all the events within that window calculate the mean, max, 95th percentile, and 99th percentile.

And this currently works very well, but I have implemented this within a for loop. The result is that it takes a rather long time: over 5 seconds on an i7 CPU) to analyze 18K events and convert them into 177 5-minute intervals. This is still faster than Splunk for the same function. But it seems that there might be an existing R function that I should be using instead.

For example, here is the head(data) of my "raw" data frame. Well, almost raw, anyway: The rows are reversed if required to ensure that the rows are sorted from oldest to newest, and the event.datetime column has been added with the results from strptime as applied to the X_time column:

```
DATA HEAD:
                            X_time CODE RTIME      event.datetime
18867 2014-08-20T00:00:17.971+0000    0 0.144 2014-08-20 00:00:17
18866 2014-08-20T00:00:17.973+0000    0 0.146 2014-08-20 00:00:17
18865 2014-08-20T00:00:18.156+0000    0 0.328 2014-08-20 00:00:18
18864 2014-08-20T00:00:18.177+0000    0 0.349 2014-08-20 00:00:18
18863 2014-08-20T00:00:18.264+0000 2057 0.437 2014-08-20 00:00:18
18862 2014-08-20T00:00:18.294+0000    0 0.467 2014-08-20 00:00:18
```

And via dput():

```
DPUT DATA HEAD:
structure(list(X_time = c("2014-08-20T00:00:17.971+0000", "2014-08-20T00:00:17.973+0000", 
"2014-08-20T00:00:18.156+0000", "2014-08-20T00:00:18.177+0000", 
"2014-08-20T00:00:18.264+0000", "2014-08-20T00:00:18.294+0000"
), CODE = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), RTIME = c(0.144, 
0.146, 0.328, 0.349, 0.437, 0.467), event.datetime = structure(c(1408492817.971, 
1408492817.973, 1408492818.156, 1408492818.177, 1408492818.264, 
1408492818.294), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC")), .Names = c("X_time", 
"CODE", "RTIME", "event.datetime"), row.names = c(18867L, 
18866L, 18865L, 18864L, 18863L, 18862L), class = "data.frame")
```

And here is the head(stats.data) of the statistics, with one row for each 5-minute time interval that contains the statistics for that row (including the count of the number of original data rows that contributed to those statistics). In this case, it is the RTIME (response time, in seconds) column from the original data that is being analyzed for the Max, Avg (mean), 95th percentile, and 99th percentile:

```
STATS HEAD:
                Start Count   Max       Avg Perc95  Perc99
1 2014-08-20 00:00:17   151 0.545 0.3369073 0.4650 0.50200
2 2014-08-20 00:05:23   130 0.487 0.3543385 0.4630 0.47913
3 2014-08-20 00:10:28   158 0.492 0.3340190 0.4520 0.48315
4 2014-08-20 00:15:33   143 0.515 0.3547133 0.4518 0.49222
5 2014-08-20 00:20:39   115 0.469 0.3311739 0.4453 0.45616
6 2014-08-20 00:25:41   157 0.454 0.3262420 0.4440 0.45200
```

And via dput():

```
DPUT STATS HEAD:
structure(list(Start = structure(c(1408492817.971, 1408493123.391, 
1408493428.267, 1408493733.976, 1408494039.253, 1408494341.597
), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), Count = c(151L, 
130L, 158L, 143L, 115L, 157L), Max = c(0.545, 0.487, 0.492, 0.515, 
0.469, 0.454), Avg = c(0.336907284768212, 0.354338461538462, 
0.334018987341772, 0.354713286713287, 0.331173913043478, 0.326242038216561
), Perc95 = c(0.465, 0.463, 0.452, 0.4518, 0.4453, 0.444), Perc99 = c(0.502, 
0.47913, 0.48315, 0.49222, 0.45616, 0.452)), .Names = c("Start", 
"Count", "Max", "Avg", "Perc95", "Perc99"), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

I mostly ask because this seems to be a common problem and I assume that my inability to find a built-in R solution is my fault in the looking, and not R's actual lack. In addition, all of the other processing including reversing the rows and converting the ISO-8601 X_time column to the R date/time event.datetime column is blindingly fast, and it's my row-by-row collection of events into their proper fixed-width time interval that is the one blight on an otherwise lightning-fast script.

Comment: There are both `cut.` and `seq.` methods for POSIXlt objects. If you had posted `dput(head(stats.data))` you would have gotten a worked example,. It's a real PITA to try to rebuild such objects from console output.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the pointers. Based on your suggestions, I used seq to generate a time interval sequence, and then cut to create a factor with the appropriate assignment of each row to its proper time interval. I then used the by function to process each time interval as its own separate data frame. But some points of interest for anyone else who is doing this:

From my (time-sorted; it's from log files) data, I found the start and end times and then used seq with a POSIXlt object as the interval. It worked fine, but I needed to add the interval to the end time to prevent the ending interval's rows from being classified as NA by cut:

```
interval_set = seq(from=start_time, to=end_time + interval_size, by=interval_size)

data_factors = cut(data$event.datetime, interval_set, include.lowest=TRUE, right=FALSE)
data_factors = droplevels(data_factors)
```

Inside my callback function, the event time comes back as a string, even though it's stored in the orignal data frame (all rows across all intervals) as proper R POSIXlt objects. No big deal, just need to call strptime again but with a slighly different (the default, actually) time string:

```
calcStats <- function(df) {
   start_time <- strptime(df[1, "event.datetime"],
                          format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz="UTC")

   values <- df[,"RTIME"]
   n_values <- length(values)

   max_value <- max(values, na.rm=TRUE)
   avg_value <- mean(values, na.rm=TRUE)
   percs <- quantile(values, probs = c(0.95, 0.99), na.rm=TRUE)

   stats_df <- data.frame(
         Start=start_time,
         Count=n_values,
         Max=max_value,
         Avg=avg_value,
         Perc95=percs[1],
         Perc99=percs[2])

   return (stats_df)
}
```

The call to the call-back via by seems as if it needs to be:

```
result <- by(data, data_factors, function(arg) { return (calcStats(arg)) })
```

I noticed that my function isn't called for any interval that has no rows in it. This is kind of a shame, as the factor contains named rows with NULL data, and the name can be used to create a explicit count of all 0's for that interval. Hence the call to droplevels against the factor generated by cut.

I could not make heads or tails of the result from by. I can see it when I print it, and I can dput it, but I cannot make it into anything useful programmatically. Googling for R and by is an exercise in futility. But I could create my time series using the dreaded for loop; this worked fine:

```
result_frame <- NULL
for (i in result)
{
   if (!is.null(i))
   {
      if (is.null(result_frame))
      {
         result_frame <- i
      } else
      {
         result_frame <- rbind(result_frame, i)
      }
   }
}
ts_stats_data = ts(result_frame)
```

And basic plotting works fine. Now onto improving the plots and then packaging all this nicely.

And this for loop is actually lightning fast; it doesn't affect the instantaneous operation of this script as it converts 18K rows of a CSV file into a nice time interval chart with all the stats that are needed, still in the blink of an eye (less than a couple milliseconds).

I suppose I could update calcStats function to add each data frame directly to a globally accessible data frame and eliminate the for loop. But that's sliding down the slope of diminishing returns.

And thanks again to BondedDust for the references to seq and cut. That's all the inspiration I needed.